# Spring, JPA, Hibernate, Tomcat: Unable to find persistence unit when loading Spring application context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, tomcat7

I have an application context where I am trying to setup JPA:

**application-context.xml**:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="persistenceUnits">
        <map>
            <entry key="pu1" value="pu1" />
            <entry key="pu2" value="pu2" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="pu1" />
</bean>

<bean id="emf1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu1" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
</bean>

<bean id="emf2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2005Dialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu2" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
</bean>

<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf1" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf2" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/db/database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>  
</bean>

<!-- The actual config of the database is read from the properties file database.properties -->
<bean id="dataSource1" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:acquireIncrement="5" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="14400" p:maxPoolSize="50" p:maxStatements="15"
    p:minPoolSize="5" p:testConnectionOnCheckout="true" p:preferredTestQuery="SELECT 4;"
    p:driverClass="${db.system1.driver}" p:jdbcUrl="${db.system1.url}" p:user="${db.system1.user}" p:password="${db.system1.password}" />

<bean id="dataSource2" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" p:acquireIncrement="5" p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60" p:maxPoolSize="10"
    p:maxStatements="50" p:minPoolSize="3" p:testConnectionOnCheckout="true" p:preferredTestQuery="SELECT 4;"
    p:driverClass="${db.system2.driver}" p:jdbcUrl="${db.system2.url}" p:user="${db.system2.user}" p:password="${db.system2.password}" />

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.model.manager"/>
```

**persistence.xml**:

```
<persistence-unit name="pu1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.myapp.model.Address</class>
    <class>com.myapp.model.AgressoFile</class>
    <class>com.myapp.model.CustomerGroup</class>
    ...
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="pu2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.myapp.model.CompetenceArea</class>
    <class>com.myapp.model.CompetenceAreaCategory</class>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

I am loading application context in a **web.xml** this way:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**CompetenceAreaManager** class that locates in the scanned package "com.myapp.model.manager" has the following content:

```
@Service
public class CompetenceAreaManager {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "pu2")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<CompetenceArea> getCompetenceAreas() {
        List<CompetenceArea> competenceAreaList = null;
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery(CompetenceArea.FIND_ALL);
        competenceAreaList = q.getResultList();
        return competenceAreaList;
    }

    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run the application in Tomcat 7.0, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'competenceAreaManager': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain EntityManagerFactory [pu2] from JNDI
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain EntityManagerFactory [pu2] from JNDI
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getPersistenceUnit(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    ...
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [pu2] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [pu2].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    ...
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configure the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor with persistenceUnits, you are informing the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor that PUs come from JNDI (as the javadoc for setPersistenceUnits() methods mentions it). The stack trace actually shows the failing JNDI lookup.

Since you are using `<context:annotation-config/>` in application-context.xml, you don't need to declare a PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, because one will be automatically registered, which looks up PUs by reading your META-INF/persistence.xml files located in the classpath, which is actually what you expect.

Your configuration should be as simple as this :

**persistence.xml** remains unchanged

**CompetenceAreaManager**

As Sergey Makarov mentions it, just inject EntityManager with @PersistenceContext instead of injecting EntityManagerFactory with @PersistenceUnit. The em is transactional (thus bound to the thread, thus ensuring thread-safety for your DAO), and you can still configure @PersistenceContext with unitName in order to specify the PU the EM has to be bound to.

**application-context.xml**

Just drop the declaration of the PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean. The rest of the file remains unchanged.

I haven't tried your particular config (2 PUs), but the configuration I mention is the one I have always been using, with success.

Answer (score 1):

As far I understood from my recent expirience of setting up 2 EntityManagerFactory in the same application - @PersistenceUnit(unitName="myPU") just doesn't work at all.

I would suggest to inject EntityManager, not EntityManagerFactory. This is clear since you always know which EMF is used. Same for specifying right TransactionManager.

Updated code of the service class:

```
@Service
public class CompetenceAreaManager 
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "emf1")
    private EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(transactionManager="transactionManager1", readOnly=true)
    public List<CompetenceArea> getCompetenceAreas() 
    {
        List<CompetenceArea> competenceAreaList = null;
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery(CompetenceArea.FIND_ALL);
        competenceAreaList = q.getResultList();
        return competenceAreaList;
    }
}
```

Such injection is safe since Spring injects a proxy of EntityManager, which guarantees thread-safety.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My setup does work if I move those lines from application context to servlet context of DispatherServlet:      `<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.model.manager"/>`. The thing is that I want to keep them in the application context.

Comment: I guess you need to update your post with the description of DispatcherServlet configuration.

Comment: Hmm... Frankly speaking I added DispatherServlet to the application just for testing purposes in order to see, what happens if I move "component-scan" to its context. It is not actually related to the question I posted, so I will probably not post the configuration here in order not to confuse the readers.